# Chrome redirecting http -> https

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, redirection

I have two instances of chrome running (two different user profiles), in the same machine. In one, typing `http://localhost:8000` redirects to `https://localhost:8000`. In  the other instance, the redirection is not taking place. This happens at the browser level (the server is the same for both frontend instances)

I would like to remove the redirection. How can I clean this redirection in `Chrome`?

I am running Chrome:

```
Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

In:

```
» hostnamectl 
...
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Go to **chrome://net-internals/#hsts**.
- scroll down to the **Delete
  domain security policies** area.
- Type in the domain for which you
  want to prevent redirection. Click on **Delete.**

Then, go to history, and clear your cache in **Clear Browsing data..** and make sure that you remove all cached files and cookies.

Now it should stop redirection from http to https **only** for that specific domain.

Comment: This no longer works as chrome://net-internals/#hsts is disabled.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, I was having trouble for "localhost" so I have entered Domain Name: localhost and deleted the domain security policy

Comment: It doesn't persistent! How should I keep this persistent?